# Adding name to worksheet with Excel VBA names.add does not work as expected

Tags: excel, vba

Worksheets("...").Names.Add adds a name but changes the "RefersTo" string in a manner that the added name is worthless.
All details please find in the comments of the sub below.
Effective VBA code producing the unusable name is only three lines (at the end).

```
Sub Test2_AddingName_RefersTo_WS3_A1()
'
' Preparations
' 1. Create a new xlsm and put this Sub in a Module
' 2. Create a worksheet named "Test Wrksht 3"
' 3. (optional) Put some unique strings into A1 and A2 on that worksheet
' 4. Select cell A1 on worksheet "Test Wrksht 3" before running the 
'    Sub (=macro)
' 5. Run this Sub (=macro)
'    Expectation from it is, that a name is added and that this name
'    is related to the worksheet (NOT the workbook) and that it refers to
'    $A$1 on worksheet "Test Wrksht 3"
'    Observed results are documented below.
'
' Microsoft documentation:
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name.refersto
' "Returns or sets the formula that the name is defined to refer to,
'  in the language of the macro and in A1-style notation, beginning
'  with an equal sign. Read/write String."
'
'
' Observed result (see also enclosed screenshot):
' 1. Name "WS3_A1" was added =ok
' 2. Name relates to worksheet "Test Wrksht 3" =ok
' 3. Name relates to 'Z1S1' =NOT ok; expectation is $A$1
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Wrksht 3").Names.Add Name:="WS3_A1", _
        RefersTo:="='Test Wrksht 3'!$A$1"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Wrksht 3").Names("WS3_A1").Comment = ""
End Sub
```

Image (from Excel name manager) shows that Excel VBA has changed the "RefersTo" string
[image]

Comment: That's strange! I ran your exact code but didn't observe the same behavior. Using Excel 2016

Comment: Also unable to reproduce.

Comment: Thank you so much for checking it!
I'm running the following Excel version (should be up-to-date):
Microsoft® Excel® für Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2207 Build 16.0.15427.20182) 64 Bit

Comment: Works for me - name is added as coded.

Comment: One additional information (which MUST NOT be relevant): I'm using Excel localized for DE.

Comment: I'm somehow relieved that it seems that not everyone is affected by this strange behavior (yet).

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and I get the same useless result as you described it.

I don 't know why, but once you set the RefersTo parameter and then you change the comment, the RefersTo parameter gets quotes on both sides as if it was a string. Instead if you leave the comment out or set it before the RefersTo parameter, then it works properly.

So first instantiate the name with the RefersTo parameter, then set the comment and in the last step set the RefersTo argument again.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Wrksht 3").Names.Add Name:="WS3_A1", RefersTo:="='Test Wrksht 3'!$A$1"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Wrksht 3").Names("WS3_A1").Comment = ""
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Wrksht 3").Names.Add Name:="WS3_A1", RefersTo:="='Test Wrksht 3'!$A$1"
```

Or even a better style:

```
Dim myName As Name
Set myName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Wrksht 3").Names.Add(Name:="WS3_A1", RefersTo:="='Test Wrksht 3'!$A$1")
With myName
    .Comment = ""
    .RefersTo = "='Test Wrksht 3'!$A$1"
End With
```

Also if the second equal-sign in `RefersTo:="='Test Wrksht 3'!$A$1"` is omitted, it becomes a string.

I hope it helps

Beste regards,
John